# how to group the information inside the first file based on information from a second file?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have two files:

```
File1:

234 235 283
567 
1001 
1002 1009


file2:

234 235 283 567 1001 1002 1009
1 1 2 1 2 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 2 2
1 2 2 2 2 2 2

I want in the output the rows in file2 be grouped similar to file 1:

output:
234 235 283   567   1001   1002 1009
1 1 2          1     2      0 1
0 0 0          0     0      2 2
1 2 2          2     2      2 2
```

and in the final output there should not be any space between digits in a gruop and also the first row should not be there any more:
 final output:

```
112 1 2 01
000 0 0 22
122 2 2 22
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{n+=NF;a[n]=" ";next} FNR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s%s",$i,a[i]; print""}' file1 file2
112 1 2 01 
000 0 0 22 
122 2 2 22
```

#### How it works

We first read `file1` and use the number of fields on each line to determine where spaces should be inserted in the output.  Then, we read file2 and insert the spaces.

- `FNR==NR{n+=NF;a[n]=" ";next}`

  This command is performed when reading the first file.  `NF` is the number of fields on the current line.  `n` is the cumulative number of fields seen.  We insert a space into array `a` for every `n`.  (Other values will default to an empty string.)
- `FNR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s%s",$i,a[i]; print""}`

  For lines after the first, we print each field numbered `i` followed by `a[i]`.  When we have printed all the fields on this line, we use `print` to print a newline character.

Comment: Does your file1 has all 50,000 fields in it?